# The Exit Button Covers the whole screen

Tags: java, swing, button

The exit Button covers the whole screen what is wrong??

the bounds I set covers the text Exit so the bounds are x-280,y-385,width-70,height-20.

The Image of the button covering the whole Frame

[image: The Image of the button covering the whole Frame]

Note: I tried the same code in my laptop and it works comepletely fine but when I run it in my school computer it starts acting all weird!

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "serial" })
public class FinalBlowzXC extends JFrame{

    public JLabel bgmainmenu;
    public JButton start;
    public JButton exit;
    public static JPanel mainmenu;
    public static JPanel login;

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        new FinalBlowzXC().setVisible(true);
    }

    public FinalBlowzXC()
    {
        super("Final Blowz Xchanged");
        setSize(640,480);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        bgmainmenu = new JLabel();
        start = new JButton();
        exit = new JButton();

        mainmenu=new JPanel();

        bgmainmenu.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/FF-XV.jpg")));
        bgmainmenu.setBounds(0,0,640,480);
        add(bgmainmenu);
        add(start);
        start.setBounds(280, 360, 70, 20);
        start.setBorder(null);
        start.setBorderPainted(false);
        start.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        start.setOpaque(false);
        start.addActionListener(new Start());
        exit.setBounds(280, 385, 70, 20);
        add(exit);
        exit.setBorder(null);
        exit.setBorderPainted(false);
        exit.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        exit.setOpaque(false);
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });       

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The default layout manager of the content pane of a frame is the `BorderLayout`. When you add components to a BorderLayout and you don't specify a constraint the component goes to the `CENTER`. Only the last component added can be displayed in the `CENTER`.

So instead if you want to display multiple buttons you need to nest panels in the frame. Something like:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(start);
buttonPanel.add(exit);
add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples on how the `BorderLayout` works.

Answer (score 1):

The `JFrame`'s content pane has a `BorderLayout` as the default layout manager, when you add something to it with `add(Component comp)`, it gets added to the center, and occupies the whole space.

Setting the bounds has no use except if the container has a null layout (`setLayout(null)`).

With a null layout, your bounds are taken into account, but it is much advised to choose a real layout manager that fits your needs .

See here : [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)